# Session returns strange values on page reload

Tags: php, session

On page load, a counter is created. On each page load the counter should be incremented. When the page loads the first time, the counter returns zero. However, when I reload the page I get a constant value from the counter. Always 2. This is the behavior I get when there is an "init" variable in the mix. When I remove the init var, I just get 2 on first page load and after.

P.S. Session is returning 1. If I don't increment, output is 1. 2 is what I get after the increment.

Now when I run my larger script with my session and am using AJAX calls, my session behaves as expected. But as soon as I reload the page, my session wants to return 1 on my variable.

I also did a check on the session ID and it matches.

I am running XAMPP (ver 8.2.4.0) and thought maybe a reinstall would help. Same results.

**test.php** Returns 0 on first page load. Then returns 2 all other loads.

```
<?php
session_start() ;

if (!isset($_SESSION["init"])) {
   $_SESSION["init"] = true ;
   $_SESSION["quiz_number"] = 0 ;
} else {
   ++$_SESSION["quiz_number"] ;
}

echo ($_SESSION["quiz_number"]) ;
?>
```

Always returns 2.

```
<?php
session_start() ;

if (!isset($_SESSION["quiz_number"])) {
   $_SESSION["quiz_number"] = 0 ;
} else {
   ++$_SESSION["quiz_number"] ;
}

echo ($_SESSION["quiz_number"]) ;
?>
```

My AJAX call. A function is passed in an argument to receive the response from the server. The receiving function just console logs the response.

```
var load_prs = function( data_func , loc ) {
   var parsreq = new XMLHttpRequest() ;

   parsreq.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if ( (parsreq.readyState === 4) && (parsreq.status === 200) )
      {
      data_func(parsreq.responseText) ;
      }
   } ;

   parsreq.open("POST" , loc , true) ;
   parsreq.send() ;
   } ;
```

The calling function.

```
load_prs(displayResults, "test.php") ;
```

The receiving function.

```
function displayResults(response) { console.log(response) ; }
```

Been reading on stack overflow about sessions. Can't seem to find anything related. Read the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) on sessions up and down.

EDIT: I also tried storing the value as a string with a prefix (qn:) then exploding that string to get my number. but I still just get a value of 1.

TESTING: On more testing I returned session ID...

```
<?php
session_start() ;

if (!isset($_SESSION["init"])) {
   $_SESSION["init"] = true ;
   $_SESSION["quiz_number"] = 0 ;
} else {
  ++$_SESSION["quiz_number"] ;
}

echo (session_id()) ; // returns "tglih5gq8eeau35fidanl65nfr" on first page load
// on second page load returns "tglih5gq8eeau35fidanl65nfr"
?>
```

Things get more interesting when I try to store a small string...

```
<?php
session_start() ;

if (!isset($_SESSION["init"])) {
   $_SESSION["init"] = true ;
   $_SESSION["quiz_number"] = "qn:0" ;
   $qn = $_SESSION["quiz_number"] ;
} else {
   $qn = $_SESSION["quiz_number"] ;
}

echo ($qn) ; // returns "qn:0" on first page load.
// returns 1 on second page load.
?>
```

Comment: There is of course no way that a single `++$_SESSION["quiz_number"]` gets you from `0` to `2`- so the only logical conclusion is that this code executes more times, than you thought it did.

Comment: The value is actually returning 1, then getting incremented.

Comment: I thought maybe it had to do with serializing, So I triedd serializing the value then unserializing it. Same results.

Comment: I also tried storing  the value as a string with a prefix (qn:) then exploding that string to get my number. but I still just get a value of 1.

Comment: _"The value is actually returning 1, then getting incremented"_ - you said it went from 0 to 2, so where exactly is it "returning" 1?

Comment: The value of 1 is getting incremented. Session is returning 1 before the incrementing.

Comment: Where have you put the codes you have shown us? Is that just in the context of the specific page you are requesting; or perhaps in an include file, that gets used elsewhere as well - so that it might also get triggered by a _different_ request? (Like for example one the browser might automatically make, for a favicon - if you rewrite that request to your PHP somewhere, maybe because it 404s ... then that would be the explanation.)

Comment: In other words, If I don't increment, then the scripts returns 1.

Comment: I created a stripped down example to test it. I am using this exact code and getting these results.

Comment: _"In other words, If I don't increment, then the scripts returns 1"_ - if you don't increment the value _anywhere_, then how could it possibly go from the `0` you initialize it with, to `1`? This is all making rather little sense so far.

Comment: Hence why I am here for help. These results are very strange.

Comment: There are no includes. The code you see here is the code I am running.

Comment: So when you check the network panel in your browser dev tools, there is only one single request, when you reload the page? _Nothing_ else?

Comment: One request. The code you see here is all that is in the file. I created a test file with this code.

Comment: My javascript has one single AJAX call on the page load.

Comment: I am sending a $_REQUEST object with my AJAX call, but I don't see how that would affect anything in my session.

Comment: What JavaScript, what AJAX? I thought those weren't even involved here, and your problem presented with _just_ the code you have shown so far?

Comment: _"I am sending a $_REQUEST object with my AJAX call, but I don't see how that would affect anything in my session"_ - _what_ you are sending, is likely much less relevant, than _where_.

Comment: I added my AJAX call to my question.

Comment: That's just a function, what parameters you are calling it with, still unclear - so we still don't know what `loc` you are actually sending this to.

Comment: I added more code to my question. Seems like semantics really.

Comment: It's not semantics, if you want our help in debugging this, then we need to know what is happening. We are not sitting in front of the whole thing with full access like you have, for debugging purposes, so we can only work with the information we actually get from you. And without knowing what URL you are making that request to, we can't know if that is not the reason of your problem either.

Comment: If it makes you guys feel better. I replaced the echo output with a random string. I wrote "this is a random string.". My dev console showed the exact same text on page reload. Yes, my AJAX is calling the correct file. Yes, my PHP is outputting expected results. My session however, is not outputting expected results. I really wish we could move away from the client side, which is clearly not the issue here.

Comment: No one here can know where the issue lies, all we can do is give you hints on what to look for during debugging. You are the only one who has access, and can verify - or disprove - the different "theories" we can develop here. I would add some external lagging to the session code next, that logs when exactly it executes, to some text file. And then check (again), if that _really_ executes just one single time, when you _expected_ it to execute only one single time.

Comment: If the script was executing more than once, my client-side would trigger more than once. There is only one AJAX call on the client side.

Comment: _"If the script was executing more than once, my client-side would trigger more than once."_ - if there is an additional request happening, and it was not triggered by your JavaScript in the first place - then there probably won't be much of a client-side "reaction" to the response either.

Comment: If you think the script is executing more than once, then why is the output remain only 2? Why doesn't the counter keep incrementing upwards to say 13 or 5? Instead, the result is always 2 after the first page reload.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256805/discussion-between-xavier-and-cbroe).

Comment: Well sorry if trusting your problem description isn't actually that easy here, when you only reveal _important_ information one piece at a time - like the fact, that you are apparently _not_ reloading the code that contains this session update, but that this only gets requested via AJAX. (That is clear by now, but your original version of the question did not make that clear, _at all_.) So I can only ask you to double-check stuff that you say you checked already.

Comment: _"I also did a check on the session ID and it matches."_ - where and how did you check this? If you have not actually done it in there already, then please add a debug output of the session id _in_ the test.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my theory about serialization was correct. PHP is indeed serializing my session values. Using `session_encode()` to encode my value before serialization and using `session_decode()` on my page reloads was my answer.

```
<?php
session_start() ;

if (!isset($_SESSION["init"])) {
   $_SESSION["init"] = true ;
   $_SESSION["quiz_number"] = 0 ;
   $qn = $_SESSION["quiz_number"] ;
} else {
   session_decode($_SESSION["data"]) ; // decode session data for use.
   ++$_SESSION["quiz_number"] ;
   $qn = $_SESSION["quiz_number"] ;
}

$_SESSION["data"] = session_encode() ; // encode all session values.
echo ($qn) ; // Returns 0 on firt page load.
// on subsequent page loads returns 1 then 2 and 3 and so forth...
?>
```